# How to add new columns in asp.net mvc identity with entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   ......
}
```

this method can rewrite table name or column name, but how to add ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add new columns into the Identity tables, simply modify the classes created with the project template.

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
   public string UserNickName {get; set;}
}
```

And then add a new migration to tell EF to add the column to the `AppUser` which it is `AspNetUsers` table, if I'm not mistaken.

You can do this process with other Identity tables that you need to add column to (`AppUserRole`, `AppUserClaim`, etc...)

Comment: thanks for you! I tried to do under default class ApplicationUser, success to add new columns.